# How to align the following Higher High and Lower Low plotshape to RSI line in pinescript?

Tags: pine-script

Following script is a combination of RSI and Higher High and Lower Low script. The issue is that the HH LL labels are aligned for the price not on the RSI Line. How to align the labels to the RSI line? It is basically showing the Higher Highs and Lower Lows of RSI. The labels need to stick on to the respective RSI line.

```
//@version=4

study(title="RSI", shorttitle="RSI", format=format.price, precision=2)

// RSI
lenRSI = input(14, minval=1, title="Length")
srcRSI = input(close, "Source", type=input.source)

rsi = rsi(srcRSI, lenRSI)
plot(rsi, "RSI", color=color.gray, linewidth=1)

// Higher High Lower Low
lb = input(5, title="Left Bars", minval=1)
rb = input(5, title="Right Bars", minval=1)

mb = lb + rb + 1

ph = iff(not na(rsi[mb]), iff(highestbars(rsi, mb) == -lb, rsi[lb], na), na)  // Pivot High
pl = iff(not na(rsi[mb]), iff(lowestbars(rsi, mb) == -lb, rsi[lb], na), na)  // Pivot Low

hl = int(na)
hl := iff(ph, 1, iff(pl, -1, na))  // Trend direction
zz = float(na)
zz := iff(ph, ph, iff(pl, pl, na))  // similar to zigzag but may have multiple highs/lows
zz := iff(pl and hl == -1 and valuewhen(hl, hl, 1) == -1 and pl > valuewhen(zz, zz, 1), na, zz)
zz := iff(ph and hl == 1 and valuewhen(hl, hl, 1) == 1 and ph < valuewhen(zz, zz, 1), na, zz)

hl := iff(hl == -1 and valuewhen(hl, hl, 1) == 1 and zz > valuewhen(zz, zz, 1), na, hl)
hl := iff(hl == 1 and valuewhen(hl, hl, 1) == -1 and zz < valuewhen(zz, zz, 1), na, hl)
zz := iff(na(hl), na, zz)

findprevious() =>  // finds previous three points (b, c, d, e)
    ehl = iff(hl == 1, -1, 1)
    loc1 = 0.0
    loc2 = 0.0
    loc3 = 0.0
    loc4 = 0.0
    xx = 0
    for x = 1 to 1000 by 1
        if hl[x] == ehl and not na(zz[x])
            loc1 := zz[x]
            xx := x + 1
            break
    ehl := hl
    for x = xx to 1000 by 1
        if hl[x] == ehl and not na(zz[x])
            loc2 := zz[x]
            xx := x + 1
            break
    ehl := iff(hl == 1, -1, 1)
    for x = xx to 1000 by 1
        if hl[x] == ehl and not na(zz[x])
            loc3 := zz[x]
            xx := x + 1
            break
    ehl := hl
    for x = xx to 1000 by 1
        if hl[x] == ehl and not na(zz[x])
            loc4 := zz[x]
            break
    [loc1, loc2, loc3, loc4]

a = float(na)
b = float(na)
c = float(na)
d = float(na)
e = float(na)
if not na(hl)
    [loc1, loc2, loc3, loc4] = findprevious()
    a := zz
    b := loc1
    c := loc2
    d := loc3
    e := loc4
    e

_hh = zz and a > b and a > c and c > b and c > d
_ll = zz and a < b and a < c and c < b and c < d
_hl = zz and 
   (a >= c and b > c and b > d and d > c and d > e or a < b and a > c and b < d)
_lh = zz and 
   (a <= c and b < c and b < d and d < c and d < e or a > b and a < c and b > d)

plotshape(_hl, text="HL", title="Higher Low", style=shape.labelup, color=color.lime, textcolor=color.black, location=location.belowbar, offset=-lb)
plotshape(_hh, text="HH", title="Higher High", style=shape.labeldown, color=color.lime, textcolor=color.black, location=location.abovebar, offset=-lb)
plotshape(_ll, text="LL", title="Lower Low", style=shape.labelup, color=color.red, textcolor=color.white, location=location.belowbar, offset=-lb)
plotshape(_lh, text="LH", title="Lower High", style=shape.labeldown, color=color.red, textcolor=color.white, location=location.abovebar, offset=-lb)
```

[image: This is the screenshot of the indicator]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed the `location.belowbar` and `location.abovebar` with `location.absolute` and the plotshapes display (ex: if _hl is true, plot at the RSI level, otherwise pass)

```
plotshape(_hl ? rsi :na, text="HL", title="Higher Low", style=shape.labelup, color=color.lime, textcolor=color.black, location=location.absolute, offset=-lb)
plotshape(_hh ? rsi :na, text="HH", title="Higher High", style=shape.labeldown, color=color.lime, textcolor=color.black, location=location.absolute, offset=-lb)
plotshape(_ll ? rsi :na, text="LL", title="Lower Low", style=shape.labelup, color=color.red, textcolor=color.white, location=location.absolute, offset=-lb)
plotshape(_lh ? rsi :na, text="LH", title="Lower High", style=shape.labeldown, color=color.red, textcolor=color.white, location=location.absolute, offset=-lb)
```

Comment: It stays top and bottom. Not sticking to the RSI line. I was looking the label to attach on the respective Highs and Lows in the RSI.

Comment: I modified the answer.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much. It worked. had to add "rsi[5]" to get the actual position.

Comment: Right, you have the `offset` on each plotshape, you can also get rid of it and delete the `[5]`, or instead of it, you can write `[lb]`, these are few options. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This is so awesome. I am trying to modify to add the CHOCH on the RSI. So far no luck but am trying things like this. Not sure if on the right track. appreciate the help.

**CHoCH (Change of Character) conditions**

```
choch_bullish = zz and a >= b and c >= b or d >= c
choch_bearish = zz and a <=b and c <= b or d <= c
```

**Convert `zz` values to integers**

```
var int x1 = int(zz[2])
var int x2 = int(zz[1])
var y1 = ta.valuewhen(zz, rsi, 1)
var y2 = ta.valuewhen(zz, rsi, 0)
    
if choch_bullish
    choch_bullish_line := line.new(x1 = x1, y1 = y1, x2 = x2, y2 = y2, color = color.green, width = 1, style = line.style_dotted)
```